# sources.list empty on ubuntu server

Tags: server, apt, ssh

I'm a complete noobie when it comes to linux so appologies if I'm missing something obvious.  I'm trying to install ubuntu server 16.10 on a home file server I'm putting together.

During the add-module phase of the installation where i'm given the option to install openssh, samba file server and such, I get an error message and the process doesn't complete.  I'm able to finish the installation of the OS and can reboot into the terminal but when I try to sudo apt-get install openssh I'm asked to insert the ubuntu-server cd yakety-yak 16.10.  I don't have an optical drive so this is impossible.

I found a suggestion online saying to remove '/cdrom/d' from etc/apt/sources.list.  I did that but with no effect.  I ran some grep searches on the sources.list file and it appears to actually be empty.

I don't have this problem when I install ubuntu desktop.  I want to install a RAID array so I think I need to get ubuntu server working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I ran some grep searches"? Why don't you just 'cat /etc/apt/sources.list' to see if it really is empty.

Comment: Good to know.  I was trying nano and gedit but they weren't installed.  I'll have to look up cat.  thanks